# How to increment the count value in DB when button is clicked in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have **Home.blade.php** when I click the vote button in that page, the count value should increment in the candidate table.

Here my **Home.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($file as $show)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                      <img src="p3.png" alt="John" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                              <h5 class="title">President</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">Name : {{$show->name}}</p>
                               <!--  <p><button>VOTE</button></p> -->
                                 <button type="button" class="vote">VOTE</button>
                          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      @endforeach
```

I have table name called the candidate, when vote button is clicked, the count should be incremented in database. And i have controller called `HomeController` pls help me.
Thank you

```
class Homecontroller extends Controller
{
    public function pre()
    {
         $file = DB::table('candidate')
                     ->select('name','branch')
                     ->where('candidate.post_id', '=', 1)
                     ->get();

        return view('/home')->with('file',$file);

     }
}



@foreach ($file as $show)
            <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <div class="card">
                      <img src="p3.png" alt="John" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                              <h5 class="title">President</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">Name : {{$show->name}}</p>

                                 <a href="{{url("Homecontroller@count")}}"><p><button>VOTE</button></p> </a>
                          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      @endforeach
```

i have used funtion redirect to controller

in controller i have used this function

```
        public function Count(){
        DB::table('candidate')->increment('count',1);
        return view('/home');
        }
```

still its not working

this is my Route

**Route::get('/home','Homecontroller@count');**

Comment: Can you post your candidate model and controller function? What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tired with Ajax passing the value of count but i couldn't do it

Comment: Sorry, can you please edit your question with the updated information there? I can't read it as a comment

Comment: I have did only so much , anyone can suggest me how to increment the count in DB

Comment: [Read this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#increment-and-decrement) to learn about incrementing and decrementing

Comment: Thank u, but how does it get, which candidate value should be incremented, in **Home** page there will be different candidate profile with a vote button, how to pass it to controller

Comment: Show the ajax code you used in your question, along with the function code your ajax code is calling so we can help you out.

Comment: Your function name is Count but your route is Homecontroller@count . change it to Homecontroller@Count and check again .

Comment: no its not working